# JavaFX HBox HGrow Priority

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX scene that contains a `javafx.scene.layout.HBox`.  This `HBox` contains two children, a `javafx.scene.control.ComboBox` followed by a `javafx.scene.control.Spinner`.  The minimal FXML file to illustrate my problem is:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
    <ComboBox fx:id="myComboBox" />
    <Spinner fx:id="mySpinner" editable="true">
      <valueFactory>
        <SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory
              min="0" max="999" initialValue="0" />
      </valueFactory>
    </Spinner>
  </children>
</HBox>
```

In code, the `ComboBox` is being populated with very long (in characters) strings.  I am also specifying the desired width of the `Spinner`.  The following code is representative of what I am doing:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> myComboBox;

@FXML
private Spinner<Integer> mySpinner;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    myComboBox.getItems().setAll(
        "Some very long string that takes up a very large portion" +
        " of the screen.  You can probably see where this is going.");
    mySpinner.getEditor().setPrefColumnCount(3);
}
```

The desired effect is that the `Spinner` control is allocated it's preferred width, and the `ComboBox` control is given the remainder of the space.  However, what I am seeing is that since the `ComboBox` control contains at least one very long option, it is allocated almost all of the space (since its preferred width is much larger than the space allocated).  All I can see on the spinner control is the up/down arrows.

Does anyone know how I can force JavaFX to allocate the space for the `Spinner` object prior to considering the preferred width of the `ComboBox`?

Comment: the minWidth doesn't help ?

Comment: I don't know what to put in for the `minWidth`, since it depends on the font being used.  I have observed that RedHat Linux uses a much larger default font than Windows 7.  Without knowing the font beforehand (or the user-configurable settings such as font size in Windows), it is difficult to determine the magic numbers required to make `minWidth` useful.

Comment: You can get the font of the `Spinner` by: `spinner.getEditor().getFont()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your solution works, but it is simpler to set the `minWidth` of the `Spinner` object to be equal to the preferred width.  Change your original FXML to the following:

```
...
<Spinner fx:id="mySpinner" editable="true" minWidth="-Infinity">
<ComboBox fx:id="myComboBox" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="Infinity" /> 
...
```

This is equivalent to doing the following in code:

```
mySpinner.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

Leaving everything else the same, either one of these changes will produce the desired result.

Comment: I like this solution better than mine for two reasons: I didn't know you could set the `hgrow` property within the FXML, and becuase it gets rid of the magic number for `myComboBox.prefWidth`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to resolve this.  In the FXML, I need to specify both `prefWidth` and `maxWidth` on the `ComboBox` element:

```
...
<ComboBox fx:id="myComboBox" prefWidth="200" maxWidth="Infinity" />
...
```

Then, in the initialize method, I had to add the following line:

```
HBox.setHgrow(myComboBox, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

This resolved my issue.  Now I am seeing another issue, which is that the `Spinner` control is nowhere near 3-characters in size.  However, since it is off-topic, I will open another question for that pending issue.

Comment: You have to set minSize for the `Spinner`, then you won't have to set hGrow for the `ComboBox`

Comment: Can you be more specific about your recommendation of the use of `minSize`?  When I add `minWidth="1" minHeight="1"` to the `Spinner` FXML, and remove the `prefWidth` and `maxWidth` properties from the `ComboBox`, I still get an almost 0-width `Spinner` (JRE 8u77 on Win 7 Enterprise SP1 x64).  Are you seeing something different, or am I misinterpreting your recommendation?

Comment: You're right. You have to set hGrow for the comboBox. Regarding the minWidth I've added an answer